# Json containment query

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a Postgres table containing `json` column like below:

```
select * from jsontest;

 id |                         jbag                         
----+------------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{"category":"L"},{"category":"T"}]
  2 | [{"category":"C"},{"category":"L"},{"category":"T"}]
  3 | [{"category":"T"},{"category":"L"}]
(3 rows)
```

I want to be able to return all records where `jbag` contains `{"category":"T"}`. Please suggest a way to achieve this.

I have unsuccessfully tried the below

```
select * from jsontest where jbag @> '[{"category":"T"}]'

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2: select * from jsontest where jbag @> '[{"category":"T"}]';
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator `@>` works only on `jsonb` values:

```
select * 
from jsontest 
where jbag::jsonb @> '[{"category":"T"}]'::jsonb;
```

Comment: That worked like magic! Thanks a lot klin. BTW, does ::jsonb mean converting to json?

Comment: There are [two json types in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html): `jsonb` with equality operator and `json` without it. The `value::jsonb` means type cast to `jsonb`.